# Interleave 2 single dim lists into a list of lists

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have 2 lists, `{1,2,3,4,5}` and `{a,b,c,d,e}`. I want to end up with `{{1,a},{2,b},{3,c},{4,d},{5,e}}`.

Comment: That's nice. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
l1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
l2 = {a, b, c, d, e};

Partition[Riffle[l1, l2], 2]
```

```
{{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {4, d}, {5, e}}
```

Alternatively, you could try

```
l1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
l2 = {a, b, c, d, e};

Transpose[{l1, l2}]
```

```
{{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {4, d}, {5, e}}
```